# Android: Saving image to a folder

Tags: android

```
package com.example.cam_tab;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
protected Button _button;
protected ImageView _image;
protected TextView _field;
protected String _extStorageDirectory;
protected boolean _taken;

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN   = "photo_taken";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.imageView1 );
    _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
    _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button1 );
    _button.setOnClickListener( new ButtonClickHandler() );

    File folder = new    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/draw/Images");
 folder.mkdirs();
 _extStorageDirectory = folder.toString();
}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener 
{
        public void onClick( View view )
{
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "ButtonClickHandler.onClick()" );
        startCameraActivity();
    } 
}

protected void startCameraActivity()
{
    Log.i("cam_tab", "startCameraActivity()" );
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );

    File file = new File( _extStorageDirectory, System.currentTimeMillis()+"draw.jpg");
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );


        FileOutputStream fos = null;
{
   try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        if (fos != null) 
         {
            Bitmap mMergedLayersBitmap = null;
    mMergedLayersBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
}
catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Log.i( "cam_tab", "resultCode: " + resultCode );
    switch( resultCode )
   {
    case 0:
        Log.i( "cam_tab", "User cancelled" );
        break;

    case -1:
        onPhotoTaken();
        break;
}
}

protected void onPhotoTaken()
{
    Log.i( "cam_tab", "onPhotoTaken" );

_taken = true;

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );

_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

_field.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}



@Override 
protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Log.i( "cam_tab", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) {
    onPhotoTaken();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
outState.putBoolean( MainActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
}
}
```

I am not able to save the image in a folder. Please support me with a solution.
Thanks in advance. I tried many options but it always shows me error. Since, i am first time with android, i am not able to rectify it. Any help will be appreciable

Comment: what is the error in logcat..

Comment: make sure added external storage write permission in manifest.

Comment: @Youddh an error is showing near the try statement

Comment: Thanks @ilangoj bt i have added this permission

Comment: It always shows you error. You need to post the error

Comment: It is asking to add "Finally " to complete Block Statements

Comment: i have edited my program and its error free. But when i run the program i cant see the saved images anywhere... Any help will be appreciable

Comment: use log.d to print the save file location and then check the file on the specified directory.

Comment: update your logcat errors.

Comment: thanks but worked it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the path is available or not. If not you need to create parent directories

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator + "/picture/" + ".png"); 
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
    }
```

just update this code.

Comment: I have edited my code..and the issue is partially solved. Now i can see the folder created..but the image is blacked out. There is a jpg icon but when we open it it is a black screen...Any solution